# haskell depth tree

Tags: haskell

I have got a tree and I need the depth of the tree, but it doesn't work.

```
data Tree a b = Leaf a | Branch (b,Tree a b) (b,Tree a b) deriving(Eq,Show)

tree = Branch ("A",Branch("C",Leaf 3)("D",Branch("G",Leaf 7)("H",Leaf 6)))("B",Branch("E",Leaf 5)("F",Leaf 4))
```

My function:

```
depth (d,Leaf x) = 1
depth (d,Branch a b) = 1 + (max (depth a) (depth b))
```

> Couldn't match expected type `(t10, Tree t20 t10)'
>                   with actual type `Tree Integer [Char]'
>       In the first argument of `depth', namely `tree'
>       In the expression: depth tree
>       In an equation for `it': it = depth tree

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need pairs under your tree branches (that is, `(b,Tree a b)` rather than just `(Tree a b)`)?

Comment: [_Use type signatures_](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info#checklist)! Always. Here, that should pretty much solve the problem instantaneously.

Comment: I think your `Branch` is the essentially same as `Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)`: `Branch (b,Tree a b) (b,Tree a b)   ~=   Branch b (Tree a b) b (Tree a b)   ~=   Branch (b, b) (Tree a b)`. If we have `data NewTree = Leaf a | Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)`, we can get the original tree with `type OriginalTree a b = NewTree a (b, b)`.

Answer (score 5):

Your tree type:

```
data Tree a b = Leaf a | Branch (b,Tree a b) (b,Tree a b)
```

A `Tree a b` is either:

- a `Leaf` containing an `a` value; or
- a `Branch` containing two `(b, Tree a b)` pairs.

The patterns you write must follow that structure. You must match first `Leaf` or `Branch` and then whatever is inside them. So your `depth` should look like this:

```
depth :: Tree a b -> Int -- Always write signatures for your functions.
depth (Leaf x) = 1       -- There are no pairs anywhere in a Leaf.
depth (Branch (l1, t1) (l2, t2)) = 1 + max (depth t1) (depth t2)
```

The above can be made a little cleaner by noticing that, as we are not actually using the `b` "labels" and `a` "values", we can just ignore them. We do that with the `_` pattern:

```
depth :: Tree a b -> Int
depth (Leaf _) = 1
depth (Branch (_, t1) (_, t2)) = 1 + max (depth t1) (depth t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `depth` function, as you've written it, seems to take a pair as its argument: `(d, Leaf x)` for example. But you then tried to call it with just a tree. What is `d`?

Comment: d is (b,Tree a b) the first b,because you can not use two b's in a function.
i tried with just a tree,but it said i need(t0,tree t1 t0) for the function and the normal tree has got (tree t1 t0)

Comment: @duplode explained this more explicitly than me. Haskell functions work by *pattern matching*, which means that if a tree looks like `Leaf x`, you should write that case of your function as `depth (Leaf x) = 1` and so on.